# How can I get a custom datasource reference in Grails 2.4.X?

Tags: grails, groovy, datasource, grails-orm

I need to query a SQL from a custom lookup datasource in Grails 2.4.5. I cannot use projections because the SQL is too complex.

The documentation [Grails Docs](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.5/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) doesn't provide any explanation about this case.

I cannot make Views or similar structures in this lookup database.

My DataSource.groovy follows:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "none"
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXXXXX:1521/main-server"
    }
    lookup {
        dbCreate = "none"
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXXXXX:1521/lookup-server"
    }
}
```

My service class where I execute the query follows

```
class MyService {

    def dataSource

    def index() {

        // How can I define lookup datasource?
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource.lookup)

        def results = sql.rows("SELECT 1 from DUAL");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. You need to inject the Datasource by name, so instead of `dataSource` you're actually wanting `lookup`. In this example I renamed your `lookup` data source to `dataSource_lookup` so it is clearer.

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "none"
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXXXXX:1521/main-server"
    }
    dataSource_lookup {
        dbCreate = "none"
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXXXXX:1521/lookup-server"
    }
}


class MyService {

    def dataSource_lookup

    def index() {

        // How can I define lookup datasource?
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource_lookup)

        def results = sql.rows("SELECT 1 from DUAL");

    }
}
```